# unity2d: randomly change position of gameobject after it has been looped

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, random

So, I am making this little game, where the character constantly moves upwards with an autoscroll camera. The character jumps from platform to platform and as soon as a platform or a background tile is nolonger visible, i loop it back up. I assigned a range to my plattforms in which a randomizer choses a value from so that the player gets an individual set of plattforms every time he or she starts the game. the problem is the looping: since i do the randomizing in the start() functions, the random poision of the plattforms is only assigned once and then looped and looped again and again. so the game gets kinda boring after a few loops with is like after 20 seconds :D

Here is my code:

```
private float randomFloat = 0;
private int subOrAdd = 0; 

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    subOrAdd = Random.Range(1, 10);
    randomFloat = Random.Range(0f, 1.4f);

    // randomly add or subtract height of object 
    if (subOrAdd < 6)
    {
        this.transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - randomFloat);
    }
    else if (subOrAdd >= 6)
    {
        this.transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + randomFloat);
    }

}
```

Basically, I am having a hardcoded range and then randomly decide to either add or subtract the number that came out of the range. so how would i make it so, that the objects that get looped always ask for a new position? Because start is only called once as you know and even after looping, the position remains the same. I hope I made myself clear here :)

Any help would be awesome!

Here is the the code that loops the platforms:

```
public class PlattformLooper : MonoBehaviour {

public float spacingBetweenLoops = 0f;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Plattform")
    {
        Debug.Log("TRIGGERED Plattform!");

        float heightOfBGObj = ((BoxCollider2D)collider).size.y;

        Vector3 pos = collider.transform.position;

        pos.y += heightOfBGObj * (5*5)+spacingBetweenLoops;

        collider.transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just extract your randomization logic into a separate method.

```
void Start () {
    RandomizeHeight()
}

public void RandomizeHeight() {
    subOrAdd = Random.Range(1, 10);
    randomFloat = Random.Range(0f, 1.4f);

    // randomly add or subtract height of object 
    if (subOrAdd < 6)
    {
        this.transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - randomFloat);
    }
    else if (subOrAdd >= 6)
    {
        this.transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + randomFloat);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it whenever you want:

```
public class PlattformLooper : MonoBehaviour {

public float spacingBetweenLoops = 0f;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Plattform")
    {
        Debug.Log("TRIGGERED Plattform!");

        float heightOfBGObj = ((BoxCollider2D)collider).size.y;

        Vector3 pos = collider.transform.position;

        pos.y += heightOfBGObj * (5*5)+spacingBetweenLoops;

        collider.transform.position = pos;
        collider.GetComponent<YourComponent>().RandomizeHeight();
    }
}
```

Comment: but wouldnt that mean, that start is only called once the obejcts are initilazed? hence even after looping the set they still have the same y and x values?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Yes, Start() is only called once. But you can set the transform position at any time, in fact you're already doing so to achieve the looping.